# powershell script with mandatory parameters keeps prompting me to enter values despite values entered in the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell script that basically starts a work flow by requiring users to enter info that are then saved in two mandatory parameters.

The issue that I have is when I call the function in the script in Powershell ISE and pass parameter values in the following format, it works fine.

```
WithParam -Name Test -IPAddress 10.10.0.1
```

However, running the script from windows PowerShell (dot sourced) keeps prompting me to enter the values again and then it executes the workflow

```
.\WithParam.ps1 -Name Test -IPAddress 10.10.0.1
```

The message I get is `Supply values for the following parameters`

```
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [Alias('host')]
        Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias('location')]
        IPAddress       
)
```

Anything I am missing?

**EDIT**

```
function Testm {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    $Name
)
Write-Host " The server name is $Name"
```

}

Comment: FYI, what you are doing is not really dot sourcing.  You are just running a script.  Dot sourcing is something different.  As for your issue, are you calling the script again from somewhere inside the file?  Do you still have the function defined or did you remove that part and only leave the param() part?

Comment: @Daniel I am not calling the function inside the script again. I have replicated the issue to a test function (I have paste it under my original question).